# Push someone over into

Tags: phrasal-verbs

While reading Gone with the Wind I've come across this sentence:

> Aunt Pity was heaving and sighing on her shoulder and, with small ceremony, Scarlett pushed her over into a corner of the carriage and continued her reading.

[Cambridge Dictionary says](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/push-sb-sth-over) that **push sb over** means to push someone or something so that they fall to the ground. But I can't match this definition with the sentence above. Did Scarlett push Aunt Pity so that she fell into the corner of the carriage? I can hardly imagine that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a use of the phrasal verb *push over*, but the simple verb *push* and the adverb *over*, meaning, "across a space".

Comment: Thanks! It looks I'm bad at telling a phrasal verb and a verb with an adverb apart.

Comment: I don't think there's any algorithmic way of telling. Learning how to parse potentially ambiguous structures like a native is one of the hardest parts of learning a language, I think.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be "to the ground". There is not much "ground" in a carriage to fairly push someone over onto.

[image]

*Historic 'Gone With the Wind' carriage*

*over* here implies Scarlett [fell from the position that she was in before](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/push-over). Scarlett could be standing, or sitting too close to Aunt Pity, making her annoyed/uncomfortable. Then Aunt Pity pushed her over into/in the corner to free up some space and/or to distance herself from Scarlett.

Comment: As a native English speaker (though not an American), I can say that the phrasal verb _push over_ does not even occur to me when I read this passage. See my answer.